# Animate image to continuously move across the screen?

Tags: swift, xcode, image, swiftui, aspect-ratio

Regarding the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112915/how-do-i-animate-an-image-to-continuously-move-across-the-screen/72663367?noredirect=1#comment128353816_72663367) I've tried to implement the infinite image animation and it worked just fine. But as soon as I change an image to be `resizable` and `scaledtoFill` to cover the whole screen as a background, one image becomes taller than another and it looks quite awfully cut during the animation. I believe the answer is obvious but still can't find it.

Here's a code sample/example:

```
 struct ImageBackgroundView {
    @State var animate: Bool = false
    let animation: Animation = Animation.linear(duration: 10.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        HStack(spacing: -1) {
            Image("lightBackground")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                
            
            Image("lightBackground")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, alignment: .leading)
        }
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: animate ? .trailing : .leading)
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(animation) {
            animate.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Right as I said before, It works just fine with .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` which was proposed in a linked thread. I believe there's a problem in a GeometryReader that I cannot solve.
Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Try to create a [mre]. It´s hard to tell where the problem is without seeing what you have done so far. Also some screenshots of the current output and what you want to achieve could help.

Comment: I've updated the post. Please, check it out. 
And thanks in advance!

Comment: refer to tail's answer in your post. change from Image.resizable().scaledToFill() to Image.resizable()..aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't fix a thing. The second image in the HStack is still a bit taller than the previous one.

Comment: You have two images in your HStack but one has frame and another one does not have frame. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand some basics of how the images work.

-scaledtoFill: In general, this means the image will grow as much as it needs to be to fill out the layer. Does not maintain its original ratio.

-fit: Image keeps its original ratio when resizing. The image will not go out of frame.

-fill: This is probably the one that you need. fill allow the image to expand to fill out the entire layer while maintain its original ratio.